# Word wrap a string in multiple lines

Tags: c#, word-wrap

I am trying to word wrap a string into multiple lines. Every line will have a defined width.

For example, I would get this result if I word wrap it to an area of 120 pixels in width:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
>   consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed augue 
>   velit, tempor non vulputate sit amet, 
>   dictum vitae lacus. In vitae ante 
>   justo, ut accumsan sem. Donec 
>   pulvinar, nisi nec sagittis consequat, 
>   sem orci luctus velit, sed elementum 
>   ligula ante nec neque. Pellentesque 
>   habitant morbi tristique senectus et 
>   netus et malesuada fames ac turpis 
>   egestas. Etiam erat est, pellentesque 
>   eget tincidunt ut, egestas in ante. 
>   Nulla vitae vulputate velit. Proin in 
>   congue neque. Cras rutrum sodales 
>   sapien, ut convallis erat auctor vel. 
>   Duis ultricies pharetra dui, sagittis 
>   varius mauris tristique a. Nam ut 
>   neque id risus tempor hendrerit. 
>   Maecenas ut lacus nunc. Nulla 
>   fermentum ornare rhoncus. Nulla 
>   gravida vestibulum odio, vel commodo 
>   magna condimentum quis. Quisque 
>   sollicitudin blandit mi, non varius 
>   libero lobortis eu. Vestibulum eu 
>   turpis massa, id tincidunt orci. 
>   Curabitur pellentesque urna non risus 
>   adipiscing facilisis. Mauris vel 
>   accumsan purus. Proin quis enim nec 
>   sem tempor vestibulum ac vitae augue.

Comment: How would you like the result to be? A an array of strings? Or strings printed to a Bitmap? What font and size do you use?

Comment: An array of strings should be good!

Comment: Don't forget to think about what to do if you have text that has no spaces for 120 pixels.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> lines = WrapText("Add some text", 300, "Calibri", 11);

    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static List<string> WrapText(string text, double pixels, string fontFamily, 
    float emSize)
{
    string[] originalLines = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, 
        StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

    StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();
    double actualWidth = 0;

    foreach (var item in originalLines)
    {
        FormattedText formatted = new FormattedText(item, 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
            System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(fontFamily), emSize, Brushes.Black);

        actualLine.Append(item + " ");
        actualWidth += formatted.Width;

        if (actualWidth > pixels)
        {
            wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
            actualLine.Clear();
            actualWidth = 0;
        }
    }

    if(actualLine.Length > 0)
        wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());

    return wrappedLines;
}
```

Add `WindowsBase` and `PresentationCore` libraries.

Comment: Any experiences yet how much the measurement of `FormattedText` matches the rendering of WinForms text (using `Graphics.DrawString`or `TextRenderer.DrawText`)?

Comment: This is the best. Hope it can also handle when the Formatted(item).Width exceeds the max pixel provided.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version I came up with for my [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) game...

(Note that it's a snippet, not a proper class definition. Enjoy!)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

public static float StringWidth(SpriteFont font, string text)
{
    return font.MeasureString(text).X;
}

public static string WrapText(SpriteFont font, string text, float lineWidth)
{
    const string space = " ";
    string[] words = text.Split(new string[] { space }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    float spaceWidth = StringWidth(font, space),
        spaceLeft = lineWidth,
        wordWidth;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        wordWidth = StringWidth(font, word);
        if (wordWidth + spaceWidth > spaceLeft)
        {
            result.AppendLine();
            spaceLeft = lineWidth - wordWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            spaceLeft -= (wordWidth + spaceWidth);
        }
        result.Append(word + space);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks! I take a method from [as-cii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961278/word-wrap-a-string-in-multiple-lines/3961597#3961597) with some changes, for using it in Windows Forms. I am using **TextRenderer.MeasureText** instead of **FormattedText**:

```
static List<string> WrapText(string text, double pixels, Font font)
{
    string[] originalLines = text.Split(new string[] { " " },
        StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

    StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();
    double actualWidth = 0;

    foreach (var item in originalLines)
    {
        int w = TextRenderer.MeasureText(item + " ", font).Width;
        actualWidth += w;

        if (actualWidth > pixels)
        {
            wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
            actualLine.Clear();
            actualWidth = w;
        }

        actualLine.Append(item + " ");
    }

    if(actualLine.Length > 0)
        wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());

    return wrappedLines;
}
```

And a little remark: the line **actualLine.Append(item + " ");** needs to be placed after checking the width, because if actualWidth > pixels, this word must be in the next line.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string GetTextWithNewLines(string value = "", int charactersToWrapAt = 35, int maxLength = 250)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return "";

    value = value.Replace("  ", " ");
    var words = value.Split(' ');
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var currString = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (currString.Length + word.Length + 1 < charactersToWrapAt) // The + 1 accounts for spaces
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(" {0}", word);
            currString.AppendFormat(" {0}", word);
        }
        else
        {
            currString.Clear();
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, word);
            currString.AppendFormat(" {0}", word);
        }
    }

    if (sb.Length > maxLength)
    {
        return sb.ToString().Substring(0, maxLength) + " ...";
    }

    return sb.ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms):

```
List<string> WrapText(string text, int maxWidthInPixels, Font font)
{
    string[] originalLines = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

    StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();
    int actualWidth = 0;

    foreach (var item in originalLines)
    {
        Size szText = TextRenderer.MeasureText(item, font);

        actualLine.Append(item + " ");
        actualWidth += szText.Width;

        if (actualWidth > maxWidthInPixels)
        {
            wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
            actualLine.Clear();
            actualWidth = 0;
        }
    }

    if (actualLine.Length > 0)
        wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());

    return wrappedLines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the (approximate) width of a string from the System.Drawing.Graphics class using the MeasureString() method.  If you need a very precise width, I think you have to use the MeasureCharacterRanges() method.  Here is some sample code using the MeasureString() method to do roughly what you asked for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // For List<>
using System.Drawing; // For Graphics and Font

private List<string> GetWordwrapped(string original)
{
    List<string> wordwrapped = new List<string>();

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);

    string currentLine = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
    {
        char currentChar = original[i];
        currentLine += currentChar;
        if (graphics.MeasureString(currentLine, font).Width > 120)
        {
            // Exceeded length, back up to last space
            int moveback = 0;
            while (currentChar != ' ')
            {
                moveback++;
                i--;
                currentChar = original[i];
            }
            string lineToAdd = currentLine.Substring(0, currentLine.Length - moveback);
            wordwrapped.Add(lineToAdd);
            currentLine = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return wordwrapped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wanted to wrap text to draw it afterwards in my image. I tried [as-cii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961278/word-wrap-a-string-in-multiple-lines/3961597#3961597), but it didn't work in my case as expected. It always extends the given width of my line (maybe because I use it in combination with a Graphics object to draw the text in my image).

Furthermore his answer (and related ones) just work for > .NET 4 frameworks. In framework .NET 3.5 there isn't any *Clear()* function for *StringBuilder* objects. So here is an edited version:

```
    public static List<string> WrapText(string text, double pixels, string fontFamily, float emSize)
    {
        string[] originalWords = text.Split(new string[] { " " },
            StringSplitOptions.None);

        List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();
        double actualWidth = 0;

        foreach (string word in originalWords)
        {
            string wordWithSpace = word + " ";
            FormattedText formattedWord = new FormattedText(wordWithSpace,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(fontFamily), emSize, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black);

            actualLine.Append(wordWithSpace);
            actualWidth += formattedWord.Width;

            if (actualWidth > pixels)
            {
                actualLine.Remove(actualLine.Length - wordWithSpace.Length, wordWithSpace.Length);
                wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
                actualLine = new StringBuilder();
                actualLine.Append(wordWithSpace);
                actualWidth = 0;
                actualWidth += formattedWord.Width;
            }
        }

        if (actualLine.Length > 0)
            wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());

        return wrappedLines;
    }
```

Because I'm working with a Graphics object I tried @Thorins solution. This worked for me much better, as it wraps my text right. But I made some changes so that you can give the method the required parameters. Also there was a bug: the last line was not added to the list, when the condition of the if-block in the for-loop was not reached. So you have to add this line afterwards. The edited code looks like:

```
    public static List<string> WrapTextWithGraphics(Graphics g, string original, int width, Font font)
    {
        List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

        string currentLine = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
        {
            char currentChar = original[i];
            currentLine += currentChar;
            if (g.MeasureString(currentLine, font).Width > width)
            {
                // Exceeded length, back up to last space
                int moveback = 0;
                while (currentChar != ' ')
                {
                    moveback++;
                    i--;
                    currentChar = original[i];
                }
                string lineToAdd = currentLine.Substring(0, currentLine.Length - moveback);
                wrappedLines.Add(lineToAdd);
                currentLine = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        if (currentLine.Length > 0)
            wrappedLines.Add(currentLine);

        return wrappedLines;
    }
```

Comment: Re *"isn't any Clear() function"*: One can simply set the property "`Length`" for a `StringBuilder` object to 0 to clear the text content (while keeping the current capacity). [Example](https://github.com/PeterMortensen/Edit_Overflow/blob/master/Dot_NET/OverflowHelper/OverflowHelper/Source/GUI/Forms/frmMainForm.cs): `mScratchSB.Length = 0;`. It is useful for reusing a scratch string buffer (avoiding creation overhead and memory pressure).