# How to set TextWrapping to Wrap in code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word wrap a a string in multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961278/word-wrap-a-a-string-in-multiple-lines)

I know that in XAML textwrapping may be set on objects by setting `TextWrapping="Wrap"` but is there a way to do this in code behind? I am populating some listboxes and other objects with text in my code behind depending on the state of other items, but I am not able to set the textwrapping from code behind. Is this possible, and if so how could this be performed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961278/word-wrap-a-a-string-in-multiple-lines

Comment: Could you give us some sample code to look at? Which objects specifically do you want to enable `TextWrapping` on?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
yourTextBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
```