# how to reduce line number when wordwrap on and off

Tags: c#, word-wrap, line-numbers

I developed a notepad application . In that i used Line Numbers and wordwrap and all.
My Problem is when i click `wordwrapItem.Click=false` it will not reduce the line number in
Label. This is My Code:

```
private void UpdateNumberLabel  
{  
Point pos = new Point(0, 0);  
int firstIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);  
int firstLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstIndex);  

pos.X = ClientRectangle.Width;  
pos.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;  
int lastIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);  
int lastLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);  
pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(lastIndex);  
UpdateLabel.Text = "";  
int i=0;  
for (i = firstLine; i <= lastLine + 1; i++)  
{  
UpdateLabel.Text += i + 1 + "\n";                      
}  
}
```

Comment: do it inside the click event

Comment: i did it in click event only...but i dont how to reduce the line number when i unchecked the wordwrap menu....

Comment: Word wrap doesn't give you less or more lines.

Comment: refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961278/word-wrap-a-a-string-in-multiple-lines .Try .Remove()

Comment: thanks @jhyap but i need to know how to reduce the line when word wrap checked = false and line number should be increased when wordwrap checked =true......

Comment: When you debug, does it look like lastLine has the correct value? In other words, is the math correct, but the label doesn't update?