# Split String when exceed length on Roll Paper

Tags: c#, printing, drawstring

In my c# windows form application for printing I'm using roll paper. And its working well. My format is like

```
Qty Item            Price
 1  ItemName        $2.00
```

And I am using,

```
g.DrawString(item.quantity.PadRight(2) + item.menu_title.PadRight(24) + item.price, new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
                    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
```

My problem is, I tried with a long menu name, That pushes the price away. and again when I tried to calculate the menuItem length and split after a certain length and put that in a new line, I got something like,

```
this Is Like What I'm ge
tting.
```

So, my question is there any way to set a section? and split if wont fit there. like

```
|qty|    |menuTitle-grid|    |price-grid|
| 5 |    |First Menu    |    |$5.00     |
         |Title         |
| 2 |    |2nd Menu Title|    |$2.00     |
| 1 |    |Third Menu    |    |$3.00     |
         |Title         |
```

please enlighten me with a solution

Comment: Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961278/word-wrap-a-string-in-multiple-lines already?

Comment: You can pass a `Rectangle` into `DrawString` to constrain the bounds it draws to. It will also split the text on spaces.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Thanks brother. I totally forgot the term wrapping. I'll have a look now.

Comment: @DavidG, I'll check and confirm here what I got. thanks